# ADB Logcat Hangs when attempting any function

Tags: android, adb, logcat

Trying to debug an android app from my computer using Command Prompt (as admin). ADB itself appears to work fine. I can use `adb devices` and it correctly shows my phone connected. However, if I attempt to run `adb logcat` with any combination of commands, with or without filters, it goes to do that and then just hangs. It won't even display `adb logcat --help`. If I unplug the device the command prompt will stop hanging, so I feel like it's trying to do SOMETHING, but it's like logcat just doesn't want to display anything on the screen. The only thing that WILL display is --waiting for device-- if I unplug my phone before I run it.

I've made sure that my platform-tools is up to date and I have the USB driver installed. I've tried writing to an external file with `adb logcat > logcat.txt` and that makes a logcat.txt file but it remains completely blank.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something wrong with my logcat?

Comment: When you list your device with `adb devices` - what is the device's state - device, offline, unauthorized?

Comment: It shows as "device"